# what's the Mathematica command for a recursive formula?

Tags: summation, recursion, command-line

I want to know the Mathematica command for

$$f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^{a-1} \frac{f(n)}{n!}, \quad f(0)=1$$

How to write $f(0)=1$ together with the summation? I used:

```
Sum[f[a_ ]=f[n]/n!, {n,0,a-1}] , f(0)=1

Sum[f[a_ ]=f[n]/n!, {n,0,a-1}] // f(0)=1
```

but both didn't work

I know we can avoid writing $f(0)=1$ by separating the first term as

$$f(a)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}\frac{f(n)}{n!}$$

but I need the command without separation.

Thanks,

Comment: f[0]=1 and f[a_]:=Sum[f[n]/n!,{n,0,a-1}]

Comment: @lxndr can we write it in one line without using "and" ?

Comment: You can write f[0]=1;f[a_]:=Sum[f[n]/n!,{n,0,a-1}] in one line, but that's the same as above in two lines.

Comment: Thank you @lxndr it worked. All i wanted is that little sign ";" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would define

```
f[0] = 1;
f[n_ /; n >= 1] := f[n] = Sum[f[i]/i!, {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

This uses memoisation, which is not strictly necessary, but avoids unnecessary recomputation.

This gives

```
Table[f[n], {n, 0, 9}]
{1, 1, 2, 3, 7/2, 175/48, 4235/1152, 610687/165888,
439781881/119439360, 2533206460543/687970713600}
```

Comment: Writing f[0]=1 in front followed by ; then writing f[a_ ] := Sum[f[n]/n!, {n, 0, a - 1}] solved the issue. Thank you so much (+1).

Comment: Since memoisation is most often used with integer values of the argument, you may want the second definition written as `f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] = Sum[f[i]/n!, {i, 0, n - 1}]`

Comment: There is an error in this solution.  The argument in the sum needs be f[i]/i! ; otherwise your always dividing by the same value n.  I think the confusion arose because the original question used n as the incremental value; whereas n is more typically a constant.

Answer (score 8):

This can be solves as a recurrence. If you subtract an appropriate multiple of `f[n-1]` from `f[n]` then ther result of that is simply a multiple of `f[n-1]` (because all later terms were canceled).

```
recur = RSolveValue[{f[n] - (n - 1)!/n!*f[n - 1] == f[n - 1]/n!, f[1] == 1}, 
    f[n], n]

(* Out[70]= Product[(1 + (1 + K[1])! + K[1])/((1 + K[1])!*(1 + K[1])), {K[1], 
  1, -1 + n}] *)
```

Check:

```
In[72]:= Table[recur, {n, 0, 10}]

(* Out[72]= {1, 1, 1, 1/2, 7/48, 35/1152, 847/165888, 87241/119439360, \
62825983/687970713600, 2533206460543/249650812551168000, \
919252493608304383/905932868585678438400000} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for the nice command

Comment: This does not seem to be producing the correct answer.  I suggest programming the explicit expression first, then working out more efficient alternatives.

Comment: It's the correct result @Kenric, just not the result you obtained. Not much else I can say.

Comment: For f[2] you have an output of 1; however, f[2] = f[0]/0! + f[1]/1! = 1 + 1 =2. So your solution does not give the correct sequence.

Comment: If I read the original formulation correctly, `f[n]=Sum[f[j],{j,0,n-1}]/n!`. It's that denominator `n!` that causes the value of `f[2]` to be 1.

Comment: @Kenric Further to my prior comment, yes, it's quite possible I did not read or interpret the original question correctly.

Comment: `RSolve` does work: `recur = RSolveValue[{f[n] - f[n - 1] == f[n - 1]/n!, f[0] == 1}, f[n],
    n];
a[0] := 1;
a[j_ /; j >=1] := recur /. n -> j - 1
`. It is messy.

Comment: Using the notation in your comment, the problem is f[n] = Sum[f[j] / j!, {j, 0, n-1}]; f[0] = 1;  The confusion in the original question is in using "a" as the argument and "n" as the increment of the sum, which is not typical.

Comment: @Kenric, That being the case, this does simplify matters in terms of just subtracting (sans factors depending on `n`) to get a first order recurrence.

Comment: @Kenric Thanks for the clarifications by the way. I guess that makes the correct recurrence `RSolveValue[{f[n] - f[n - 1] == f[n - 1]/(n - 1)!, f[1] == 1}, f[n], n]`.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion involves setting explicitly the initial solution(s) and then defining a function that calls the previous answer and combines this with the incremental change.  I'm going to use different variables. n is typically a constant, so I'll define f[n]; and i is a typical increment for sums. In your problem both f[0] and f[1] need to be set initially:

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 1;
f[n_Integer/;n >= 2] := f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-1]/(n-1)!
```

Here are the first few instantiations:

```
f[#] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
{1, 1, 2, 3, 7/2, 175/48, 4235/1152}
```

And this expression does not try to compute NonNegative Integer inputs:

```
f[#] & /@ {-1, 1.2, -2.3, 2/4}
{f[-1], f[1.2], f[-2.3], f[1/2]}
```

For comparison, the explicit expression can also be coded in Mathematica. Here just f[0] needs to be set explicitly:

```
f[0] = 1;
f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] = Sum[f[i]/i!,{i,0,n-1}];
```

and the output is identical:

```
f[#] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} 
{1, 1, 2, 3, 7/2, 175/48, 4235/1152}
```

While both solutions work, the recursive solution will be efficient for large values of n, since it does not have to recompute the previously solved lower solutions. Although the summation also saves previous values, the full summation is computed for each new value of n.

Comment: This is a good method but I think the coefficients are not quite right because the recurrence for `f[n-1] has denominator `(n-1)!` rather than `n!`.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I believe the expression is correct.   In the question the sum is from 0 to a-1, so last summation is f[a-1]/f[a-1].  I've used n instead of a.  Also, it's not possible for the expression on the right to include f[n] since this is what's be computed.

Comment: I made no claim that `f[n]` should be on the right (though as an equation there is a symmetry property so one could put it on either side). The issue is that `f[n-1]` is defined using a denominator of `(n-1)!` whereas the denominator in defining `f[n]` is instead `n!`. If you compare your results to othe responses you will find that they differ. This denominator issue is the cause of the differences.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Thank you.  The function is correct; however, there was something incorrect about my stated answer.  To clarify this, I've rewritten the function in terms of f[a] like the original and added the exact expression as stated for comparision.

Comment: Your function is not the same as that in the original post. And your results disagree with those in three separate responses (one of which was deleted so you won't see it). And those three all agree with one another.

Comment: It seems that all of us still had mistakes in our solutions.  In my own case, for this particular recursion problem both f[0] and f[1] need to be set initially.  The recursion does not begin until f[2].  This also affected my check, since in this case f[0] needs to be set, which I had left out.  See what you think.  Mikado's solution needs to replace n! with i! but the form is what I used as a check.  I'm not sure about Lichtblau's solution.

Comment: Here are a few of the values worked out by hand.

f[0] = 1;
f[1] = f[0]/0! = 1
f[2] = f[0]/0! + f[1]/1! = f[1] + f[1]/1! = 1 + 1 = 2
f[3] = f[0]/0! + f[1]/1! + f[2]/2! = f[2] + f[2]/2! = 2 + 1 = 3
f[4] = f[2] + f[3]/3! = 3 + 3/6 = 7/2 
....
f[n_Integer/;a>=2] := f[n-1] + f[n-1]/(n-1)!

Comment: It's a first order linear recurrence. So no need for two initial values.

Comment: Yes, but f[0] is not really defined by the summation, since in that case the limit of the sum is -1 and the start is 0, so no values get added.  Perhaps Ali intended to define a different problem, but the one defined has a value for f[0] that is different from the summation.

Comment: Your remark about the headache posed by `f[0]` is exactly why I ended up recasting as a recurrence starting with `f[1]`. Stated differently, it's still a linear recurrence, but I agree it is tricky to start from 0; at least I could not figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**This is corrected version (I have deleted previous incorrect answer)**

Just to illustrate [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html):

```
f[0] := 1
f[n_ /; n >= 1] := 
 Nest[Function[{x, y}, {x + x/Factorial[y], y + 1}] @@ # &, {1, 1}, 
   n - 1][[1]]
```

So, `f/@Range[0,10]` yields:

{1, 1, 2, 3, 7/2, 175/48, 4235/1152, 610687/165888, 
439781881/119439360, 2533206460543/687970713600, 
919252493608304383/249650812551168000}

Comment: Mikado and Kenric's solutions now show the correct sequence.  You may want to check your approach against these solutions.

Comment: @Kenric thank you. I will correct. I now see my error